# How can we manually reset the offset of a kafka topic which is consumed through a spring boot java application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My requirement is to reset the offset of a kafka topic when the application has failed to process the message read from current offset of kafka topic which is consumed through a spring boot java application.
After resetting the offset manually or sending a negative acknowledgement the messages needs to be polled again  from the uncomitted offset value through the kafka consumer of spring boot java application. Can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

That is the issue with Spring Kafka versions < 2.0.1  where the failed records are lost and Listener continues reading from next offset.

If you are using Spring kafka 2.0.1+, you can use `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` which will cause the failed and unprocessed records to be sent in the next poll.

To configure the listener container with the above handler, you need to add it into `ContainerProperties`

Here is an example of KafkaListener container factory

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(this.consumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
    return factory;
}
```

Here is the detailed documentation :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_seek_to_current_container_error_handlers